# How to install jenkins plugin with Ansible Playbook? It's return "jenkins_plugin HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

Tags: jenkins, plugins, ansible

I tried to do this:
---
- hosts: all
become: yes

```
  tasks:
  - name: Install plugin
    jenkins_plugin:
     name: git
     url_username: "admin"
     url_password: "admin"
     with_dependencies: true
```

But ansible returns:

```
"TASK [Install plugin] *****************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.60.4]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "details": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "msg": "Cannot install plugin."}"
```

Answer (score 0):

its probably because you're provisioning a fresh jenkins installation via ansible on which you've initially not set an auth password.
so everytime it tries to access jenkins it gives a 403.

```html
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 15:42:48 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.2992bb22=node01wl2t408cns4sxosi4m2yzkz4.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< X-Hudson: 1.395
< X-Jenkins: 2.263.2
< X-Jenkins-Session: 08c611a1
< X-You-Are-Authenticated-As: anonymous
< X-You-Are-In-Group-Disabled: JENKINS-39402: use -Dhudson.security.AccessDeniedException2.REPORT_GROUP_HEADERS=true or use /whoAmI to diagnose
< X-Required-Permission: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
< Content-Length: 677
< Server: Jetty(9.4.33.v20201020)
<
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
```